# Slide down view in android

Tags: android, list, animation, slide

I would like to have a button in my android application trigger a slide down view of a form.  I want to have a view at the top of the screen, a list at the bottom of the screen, and I want to have the slide down form view appear between the two when a button is clicked.

I have no problem showing the view, but can't seem to animate it from hidden to shown on the screen.

Any ideas on how this could work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This may help you:

- [ANDROID ANIMATION SLIDEDOWN SLIDEUP](http://snipplr.com/view/39078/android-animation-slidedown-slideup/)
- [Android Animation Framework](http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=343)

Answer (score 8):

```
public void doSlideDown(View view){
    RelativeLayout myView = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.my_view);
        addListingView.setVisibility(myView.VISIBLE);

        Animation slideDown = setLayoutAnim_slidedown(); 
        myView.startAnimation(slideDown);
}

public void doSlideUp(View view){
    RelativeLayout myView = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.my_view);

        Animation slideUp = setLayoutAnim_slideup(); 
        myView.startAnimation(slideUp);

}

public Animation setLayoutAnim_slidedown() {

        AnimationSet set = new AnimationSet(true);

        Animation animation = new TranslateAnimation(
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
                0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, -1.0f,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f);
        animation.setDuration(800);
        animation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // MapContacts.this.mapviewgroup.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.d("LA","sliding down ended");

            }
        });
        set.addAnimation(animation);

        LayoutAnimationController controller = new LayoutAnimationController(
                set, 0.25f);


        return animation;
    }

public Animation setLayoutAnim_slideup() {

        AnimationSet set = new AnimationSet(true);

        Animation animation = new TranslateAnimation(
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
                0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, -1.0f);
        animation.setDuration(800);
        animation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                RelativeLayout bodyView = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.bodyView);
                RelativeLayout myView = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.my_view);
                addListingView.clearAnimation();
                bodyView.removeView(myView);
            }
        });
        set.addAnimation(animation);

        LayoutAnimationController controller = new LayoutAnimationController(
                set, 0.25f);

        return animation;

}
```