# Transition between activities. From ListView

Tags: android, listview, animation, expandablelistview

So, what I want to do is that when I click an item of a `ListView` the item will get on top of the screen and the items below will 'slide' down, showing the activity I want to show. I want it to look something like this:

[image: Excuse the ugly cutting and stuff]

Because my skills with GIMP aren't so good, I will try to explain better. I want something like the image but with the user clicked row it the top of the screen and the activity filling the (now) black space. When the user goes back (by the key or some button on said activity) I want the reverse animation to happen.

I've tried with this [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3693702/slide-down-view-in-android) but it isn't quite what I'm looking for, and it seems kind of resource intensive (for my requirements).

So, if anyone wants to point me in the right direction, or show me a way to do it, I'll be very thankful.

Comment: Why not use expandableListView?

Comment: ya, expandable listview, with drop down animation for child could do it.

Comment: Yes ExpandableListView + Fragmentation will do the job

Comment: Try this one:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1161999/android-accordion-widget

Comment: @Raheel So, using an ExpandableListView I'll have to make a custom adapter to have the rows like I want, and using fragments to show the info of the row. Could you clarify more on this...

Answer (score 0):

Why cant you use the [android-accordion-view](https://github.com/hamsterready/android-accordion-view)

**Sample Code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:accordion="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto/com.sentaca.android.accordion"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <com.sentaca.android.accordion.widget.AccordionView
            android:id="@+id/accordion_view"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            accordion:header_layout_fold_button_id="@id/foldButton"
            accordion:header_layout_id="@layout/accordion_header"
            accordion:header_layout_label_id="@id/foldText"
            accordion:section_bottom="@layout/accordion_footer"
            accordion:section_container="@layout/accordion_section"
            accordion:section_container_parent="@id/section_content"
            accordion:section_headers="@array/accordion_sections"
            android:background="#fff5f5f5"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Item 1" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/example_get_by_id"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Item 2" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Item 3" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Item 4" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <RatingBar
                    android:id="@+id/ratingBar1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <SeekBar
                    android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Item 4" />
        </com.sentaca.android.accordion.widget.AccordionView>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the sample looks [like](https://github.com/hamsterready/android-accordion-view/raw/master/screenshot.png)